# MySQL inner join query select from same table multiple times

Tags: mysql, while-loop, inner-join

I believe I have formed this question title correctly because I wasn't sure how to form it. As an example, I have summarized my query below.

I have an order table which saves order details like customer id, address and product ids and quantity ordered for each order in a row. So multiple inventory/product ids are saved in a single row.

so my query looks like: this is a summarized query for an easier explanation I have omitted various other fields.

```
SELECT customer.name,customer.address,tbl_order.order_date,tbl_order.product1_id,tbl_order.product2_id,inventory.product1_name,inventory.product2_name 
FROM tbl_order 
INNER JOIN customer ON tbl_order.customer_id = customer.id 
INNER JOIN inventory on tbl_order.product1_id = inventory.id 
INNER JOIN inventory on tbl_order.product2_id = inventory.id 
where  YEAR(tbl_order.order_date)='$year'
```

So my question is how to get the inventory details from the inventory table based on each product id from tbl_order. I am running a while loop to show all data for a year

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql1))
```

I can divide this query into 2 and run the inventory query individually but then how to combine the while loop, as sometimes there could also be empty query when some products are not in order table (depending on order to order, not all products are ordered) so this doesn't work

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql1)) and ($row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($inv1)) and ($row2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($inv2))
```

and so one for 10 products

Comment: This is not a great database design. If an order has multiple products, it's much better to have two separate tables: one for the order, another for each product in the order.

Comment: If you can have up to 10 products per order then you would be better 'normalising' the order using union all before joining customer and inventory - this may not be quick but you are limited by your design..

Comment: Also see about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries, and note that functions cannot use indexes, so a range condition would be preferable

Comment: thanks guys for the db design que, unfortunately its not possible to make changes to DB at this stage. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, of all you have bad DB design and I kindly advice to normalize your DB.

Second, if you can not re-design the DB you can use multiple joins with aliases like:

```
SELECT
    customer.name, customer.address, tbl_order.order_date, 
    tbl_order.product1_id, inv1.product1_name,
    tbl_order.product2_id, inv2.product2_name 
FROM tbl_order 
INNER JOIN customer ON tbl_order.customer_id = customer.id 
INNER JOIN inventory AS inv1 ON tbl_order.product1_id = inv1.id 
INNER JOIN inventory AS inv2 ON tbl_order.product2_id = inv2.id 
WHERE  YEAR(tbl_order.order_date)='$year'
```

Comment: Hi Slava, thanks for answering. This is a great approach but it only works when product1_id, product2_id, product3_id all have values in order table. sometimes only 2 products are ordered so product3_id , product4_id could be 0 in that case the query returns no results.

Comment: i was able to get results by using LEFT JOIN inventory when there are empty values for product_ids. many thanks slava again. Unfortunately its not possible to change the db structure at this stage.

Comment: @abey if not now, when?